# Use property name stored in const in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I want to access to a property whose name is stored in a const.

```
class Foo
{
     const PROPERTY_NAME = 'bar';

     protected $bar;

     public function getBar() {
         return $this->self::PROPERTY_NAME;
     }

}
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
 public function getBar() {
     return $this->{self::PROPERTY_NAME};
 }
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/702690)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MyClass
{
    const MYCONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::MYCONSTANT. "\n";
    }
}

$classname = "MyClass";
echo $classname::MYCONSTANT. "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0
```

// Output: constant value